# PHP: Validation for required field

Tags: php

I want to validate a field which is required. I am using following condition to check whether the field is not empty:

```
isset($value) && !empty($value)
```

But if I write `0` in the fields, it will still say the field is required. The `empty()` function considers 0 as an empty value as told in PHP manual but what else should I do? I have tried writing many conditions but they didn't work as expected.

I saw user contributions and found:

```
empty($var) && !is_bool($var)
```

I tried adding it to my condition like this but didn't work:

```
isset($value) && !empty($value) && is_bool($value)
```

Comment: What's actually saved in the `$value` when you `var_dump` it?

Comment: Of what type is the variable you are trying to validate?

Comment: @ParagTyagi I'm making my own premium validation class. There isn't one value, I'm writing a single condition for integer type values and string type values.

Comment: Just a sidenote, this expression is redundant: isset($value) && !empty($value). empty() also checks if the variable is set, so there's no need to do a isset() check.

Comment: @VladCazacu isset checks whether variable is set & is not null while empty checks that variables is not null.

Comment: @MuhammedTalhaAkbar straight from the PHP doc for empty: `No warning is generated if the variable does not exist. That means empty() is essentially the concise equivalent to !isset($var) || $var == false.`

Comment: @Muhammed, that's not true. "No warning is generated if the variable does not exist. That means empty() is essentially the concise equivalent to !isset($var) || $var == false." from the PHP docs. See here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: Checkout answer. If the demo and explanation helps.

Answer (score 1):

**Try below code:**

```
$value = 0;

if(isset($value) && $value !== "")
{
    echo "Field not required";
}
else
{
    echo "Field required";
}
```

**Output:**

Field not required

**Demo:**

http://3v4l.org/JWJbj

**Explanation:**

The integer 0 is **truthy**. It means that anything that checks it in a **boolean'ish** manner will treat it as false. In particular, **`!empty($value)`** will evaluate to **`false`**, so is_numeric would never even get a chance to fail.

Short version:  empty is too wishy-washy in this case. Check for `null` and `''` explicitly (with data-type hence used `!==`).

Answer (score 0):

You can't check for empty. Basically you can only stick to the isset test.

If a field in the form was not filled this variable field will not be inside the $_POST superglobal and isset will return false. If the user typed 0 the variable name will exist inside $_POST isset will return true.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it as following:

```
function emptyTextValue($value)
{
    return trim((string) $value) !== '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You know that all you get is a string, so you don't need full functionality of empty() function:

```
isset($_POST['yourFieldName']) && $_POST['yourFieldName'] !== ''
```

Comment: Be wary of whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the empty function by :

```
$value !== ""
```

If it's not exactly empty, then it will validate the condition.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done for my test is convert the empty check to a strlen check. Because PHP is so friendly, you can run a string comparison on the value. A value of null will return a 0 length string, while a value of 0 will return a length of 1. So what I've done is this:

```
if(isset($val) && strlen($val) > 0){
    // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
isset($value) && $value != ''
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a nice condition by myself.

```
$value === 0 || $value === "0" ? isset($value) : isset($value) && !empty($value)
```

This works perfectly for every case.

Answer (score 0):

I would check to be sure that the form had been submitted and then trim the field 'msg' in case there were any white space chars, i.e. newlines, carriage returns, tabs, spaces and then test that result to make sure it's not the empty string as follows:

```
<?php
if ( isset($_POST['msg']) && trim($_POST['msg']) !== '') {

    // other code

}
```